# How to fix "push is not a function"?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a delete button to remove item rows from a table, but I am constantly encountering an "Uncaught TypeError: deletedArr.push is not a function". I am not sure what to do. Here is the code:

```
//Remove buttom
$(document).ready(function() {
   // As soon as jquery loads, load from storage
   // it will return null if nothing is stored yet
   const deletedExpenses = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('deletedExpenses')) || [];

   $('body').on('click', '.deleteButton', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); // prevent the href default 
     // if you need to access the id...
     let deleteID = $(this).data('id');
     $(this).closest('tr').remove();

     // You first have to load from storage the array of deleted items,
     var deletedArr = localStorage.getItem("deletedExpenses");

     // If you have nothing stored, this will return null,
     // And if that's the case, create new array
     if (!deletedArr){
       deletedArr = [];
     }
     
     // then push to this array another ID that got deleted
     deletedArr.push(deleteID);
     localStorage.setItem('deletedExpenses', JSON.stringify(deletedArr));
   })
```

Comment: just json parse the value that you get from localstorage

Comment: localStorage is stored as strings. You probably need to convert the contents before trying to push

Comment: _“I’m not sure what to do”_ — Learn about [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).
Please try using the [debugging capabilities](//ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-easily-debug-in-javascript-5bac70f94f1a) of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

This sets the variable to a string:

```
var deletedArr = localStorage.getItem("deletedExpenses");
```

When you set the local storage value you encode it to JSON, so you need to parse it back *from* JSON when reading it:

```
var deletedArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("deletedExpenses"));
```

Comment: I tried this but It's still giving me the same error for some reason